# Groovy + Spring - DI with no boilerplate (constructor) code

Tags: spring, groovy

I have created spring-boot project which bases on Groovy instead of Java.

Now I have following **@RestController**:

```
@RestController
class HelloRest {

    private final HelloService helloService

    @GetMapping("hello")
    String hello(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        helloService.createHelloMessage(name)
    }
}
```

Question is how to inject

```
@Service
class HelloService {...}
```

in most simple way avoiding boilerplate (in this case the constructor) code?

In Java I would use: **@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor** and in fact it works also if I use it in my groovy project.

On the other hand for example the **@Immutable** annotation from **groovy.transform** doesn't work as it creates in fact more than single constructor. Whereas Spring expects single constructor to be able automatically **@Autowired** the dependencies.

As far I see 2 solutions:

- Generate the constructor
- Use lombok with its annotations

Is there any solution build into Groovy which could be used here instead?

Comment: Do you want `private final HelloService helloService` it to be final? If you cant change that, i'm afraid constructor is your only option, but if you can remove `final`, then i think you can use setter with `@Autowired` or just `@Autowired` above field like you would usually do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At this moment there is no Groovy mechanism that does same thing as [`@lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor). The main problem in your case is that Groovy always generates no-args default constructor for all currently known features like `@Immutable` annotation. The closest (but not accurate) way is to use [`@TupleConstructor`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/api/groovy/transform/TupleConstructor.html) like:

```
@RestController
@TupleConstructor(includes = ['helloService'], includeFields = true, includeProperties = false, force = true)
class HelloRest {

    private final HelloService helloService

    @GetMapping("hello")
    String hello(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return helloService.createHelloMessage(name)
    }
}
```

This Groovy code will produce bytecode similar to this Java code:

```
@RestController
@TupleConstructor(
    includeFields = true,
    force = true,
    includeProperties = false,
    includes = {"helloService"}
)
public class HelloRest implements GroovyObject {
    private final HelloService helloService;

    public HelloRest(HelloService helloService) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        MetaClass var3 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var3;
        this.helloService = (HelloService)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(helloService, HelloService.class);
    }

    public HelloRest() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        this((HelloService)null);
    }

    @GetMapping({"hello"})
    public String hello(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        return (String)ShortTypeHandling.castToString(var2[0].call(this.helloService, name));
    }
}
```

It is almost what you need, except this default constructor that was generated as well.

Things are getting even more complicated when using [`@Immutable`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.12/html/api/groovy/transform/Immutable.html) annotation, because this version would generate 3 constructors:

- `public HelloRest(HelloService helloService)`
- `public HelloRest()`
- `public HelloRest(HashMap args)`

Of course in this case you would have to remove `private final` in front of `HelloService` field definition, because this AST transformation works only with fields that are not yet final.

In this case two options you have found (creating construct manually or using Lombok) are probably the best solutions to your problem.

#### Alternative solution

There is also one "dirty" solution that allows you to write less amount of code, but promotes injection by reflection. Consider following code:

```
@RestController
class HelloRest {

    @Autowired
    private final HelloService helloService

    @GetMapping("hello")
    String hello(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        return helloService.createHelloMessage(name)
    }
}
```

It will generate bytecode similar to following Java code:

```
@RestController
public class HelloRest implements GroovyObject {
    @Autowired
    private final HelloService helloService;

    public HelloRest() {
        CallSite[] var1 = $getCallSiteArray();
        MetaClass var2 = this.$getStaticMetaClass();
        this.metaClass = var2;
    }

    @GetMapping({"hello"})
    public String hello(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
        CallSite[] var2 = $getCallSiteArray();
        return (String)ShortTypeHandling.castToString(var2[0].call(this.helloService, name));
    }
}
```

Even though there is only single default constructor that does not even touch our `helloService` field, Spring bean will get injected by reflection. I share this option only to show all alternatives, although your initial instinct to use constructor injection is the best possible way to use dependency injection in practice.

Comment: "Dirty" solution is indeed dirty ;] Injection directly on field is deprecated. In that case always better to create constructor :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use @Cannonical or @Immutable on the class. That way the constructor will be created for you

Comment: I know that there is sth like **@Immutable** and **@Canonical** in groovy, but Groovy's **@Immutable** and **@Canonical** annotations create more than single constructor for class. Because of that in those cases **@Service** is not **@Autowired** in automatic way by spring as it is done in java in case of some **lombok** annotations. 

Seems like in groovy I am forced to generate constructor myself.